# enable / disable textarea not working for multi row

Tags: php

```
<form method="post" name="areaform" id="areaform">
<select name="city" id="city" onchange="checkCity();">
<option value="city1">city1</option>
<option value="city2">city2</option>
<option value="city3">city3</option>
</select><br />
<br />

<textarea name="description" id="description" cols="" rows="" style="width:150px; height:50px;"></textarea>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkCity() {
ct = $("#city option:selected").val();
if(ct=="city2") {
document.getElementById("description").disabled=true;
 }else{
 document.getElementById("description").disabled=false;
 }
 }
 </script>
```

The script working only for first row while fetching multiple rows the script does not work

Comment: Please clarify your question better. It's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi . I am fetching multiple row data . but the onchange script works only for the first row of form . Enabling and disabling based on drop down selection not working for rest of the rows in form.

Comment: You've shortened the code that is relevant. If you have multiple elements with the same `id`, then selecting by `id` will only select the first matching that `id`. `id` should be a **unique** identifier.

Comment: html element id should be unique. If I am not mistaken you are trying to same id for more than 1 text area.

Comment: Thanks Luke . Is there a fix for that ?

Comment: can you show some more of your code to see what you actually want to do ? What do you mean by row ?

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {   }

Comment: and then you have the above code in loop ? i guess

Comment: yes steve code goes i loop

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use same id for multiple html elements. You need to assign dynamic ids to the elements and process them according to the clicked element. use auto increment id or user defined increment variable along with fixed id string. ex, city_(increment_value) and description_(increment_value). then pass this object to javascript function. It will be easy to process each items.

```html
<form method="post" name="areaform" id="areaform">
 <select name="city" id="city_1" onchange="checkCity(this);">
  <option value="city1">
   city1
  </option>
  <option value="city2">
   city2
  </option>
  <option value="city3">
   city3
  </option>
 </select>
 <br />
 <br />
 <textarea name="description" id="description_1" cols="" rows="" style="width:150px; height:50px;">
 </textarea>
 <select name="city" id="city_2" onchange="checkCity(this);">
  <option value="city1">
   city1
  </option>
  <option value="city2">
   city2
  </option>
  <option value="city3">
   city3
  </option>
 </select>
 <br />
 <br />
 <textarea name="description" id="description_2" cols="" rows="" style="width:150px; height:50px;">
 </textarea>
 <select name="city" id="city_3" onchange="checkCity(this);">
  <option value="city1">
   city1
  </option>
  <option value="city2">
   city2
  </option>
  <option value="city3">
   city3
  </option>
 </select>
 <br />
 <br />
 <textarea name="description" id="description_3" cols="" rows="" style="width:150px; height:50px;">
 </textarea>
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
function checkCity(obj) {
    var cid = $(obj).attr('id');
    var id = cid.substr(5);
    ct = $("#"+cid+" option:selected").val();
    if(ct=="city2") {
        document.getElementById("description_"+id).disabled=true;
    }else{
    document.getElementById("description_"+id).disabled=false;
    }
}
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i have understood, it seems like you have the above code in loop and hence when you have one row it works fine. But as you are getting element by id, it fails when you have more than one rows.
This happens because your ids must be unique for elements.

You can use the code below which uses jQuery's Next() function to search next textarea and dsables it,to get it working :

```
<form method="post" name="areaform" id="areaform">
<select name="city"  onchange="checkCity(this);">
<option value="city1">city1</option>
<option value="city2">city2</option>
<option value="city3">city3</option>
</select><br />
<br />

<textarea name="description" cols="" rows="" style="width:150px; height:50px;"></textarea>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkCity(ele) {
    ct = $(ele).val();
    if(ct=="city2") {
        $(ele).next('textarea').prop('disabled',true);
     }else{
        $(ele).next('textarea').prop('disabled',false);
     }
 }
 </script>
```

**Edit** You need to use 'prop' instead of 'attr'

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the value attributes from your `<option>` tags as they contain the same information in the text.

You are saying that you have multiple rows, so I am assuming you have multiple forms.  If this is true, then you will want to look for your textarea within the respective `<form>`.  `parent().find()` can do this.  You should also ensure you don't have duplicate tag ids in the dom.

Use `prop()` to set the disabled boolean.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" name="areaform" id="areaform">
<select name="city" onchange="checkCity(this);">
<option>city1</option>
<option>city2</option>
<option>city3</option>
</select><br />
<br />

<textarea name="description" cols="" rows="" style="width:150px; height:50px;"></textarea>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkCity(elem) {
    if(elem.value=="city2") {
        $(elem).parent().find('textarea').prop('disabled',true);
     }else{
        $(elem).parent().find('textarea').prop('disabled',false);
     }
 }
 </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have proven in my run-able snippet that my method works.  If anyone is going to downvote my answer, do leave a comment so that I know what isn't right.  No need to troll while I am volunteering my time and trying to help someone.